# New navigation system in Discord and Slack on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation

So I'm a Note9 user. Lately, both Discord and slack updated their app to a new navigation system, where there is a toolbar at the bottom and you can swipe right and left from anywhere on your screen to see something like a hamburger layout. I guess this helped a lot after the new gesture system Android has implemented made it very hard to swipe to show the hamburger drawer.

My question is, can anyone point me in the right direction to implement something similar? I was thinking about a Pagerview, but I'm not sure that's what they're using.

Comment: hello, i have the same question, anyone can tell me?